# Where can I learn the meaning of variables in a formula?

Tags: electricity, waves

I am in a low level physics class that is taught in high school. We were given a couple formulas as seen on the board, but I don't know what the variables stand for (their names), and what units correspond to each variable.

I have searched a few formulas on Google word for word (4), but nothing positive came up. Can any one help me layout what each Variable stands for and what units they correspond to? Or maybe a website?

[image]

Comment: Which lines and in which columns contain symbols you don't understand?

Comment: All of the ones shown, I cropped and erased the formulas I already know.

Comment: In summary: you don't know what E, P, I, V, $V_{||}$, R, $R_{eff}$, q, k, F, $\lambda$, f mean?

Comment: I think I can say that E is energy or field.. V voltage, P power, K is a constant and I believe λ is amplitude.

Comment: P=power, V = electric potential (voltage), I = electric current, R = resistance, f=frequency, $\lambda$ = wavelength, T=period, d=distance, q=charge, F=force, k is Coulomb's constant

Comment: @DavePhD I reckon $E$ is the electric field and not energy.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, now I have a better foundation to work with than before. Should I just look up their units now or will some one leave a full answer?

Comment: @Hunter, oops, I edited

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew you should be able to work out the units by yourself; this will be a really good exercise for your exams. If you have any questions/problems, then let us know and we can help you. The name for $V$ is Voltage, $I$ is Ampere, $R$ is Ohm, $f$ is Hertz, $q$ is Coulomb, $F$ is Newton, but you should work out the units in terms of base units.

Comment: @Hunter will do. I'll answer the question myself then when I'm done. Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Lets start with electricity :-)

$$F=\frac{KQ_1Q_2}{r^2}$$

This formula tells us the force between two charged particles. The force is dependent on the distance between the charged particles. The constant $K=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$, basically this is the electric force constant.

$E=\frac{F}{Q}$

This formulae tells us that the strength of electric field is dependent on the force acting on a test charge. For example think of a two charged particles separated by a finite distance $n$. Then imagine you place a positive test charge that is an imaginary positive charge at a distance $\frac{n}{2}$ from the particles. Then the electric field strength produced by the object is calculated by this formula. Electric fields contain energy by the way.
$$P=VI$$
This is the power formula which says that power is equal to voltage multiplied by current
$$P=I^2R$$ 
This is an alternative version of the formula above . To derive this note that $V=\frac{I}{R}$

$$R_\text{eff} = R_1+R_2+R_3+\dots+R_n$$

This formula is used to calculate the total resistance in a series circuit.

$$\frac{1}{R_\text{eff}} = \frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}+\dots+\frac{1}{R_n}$$

This is for parallel circuits.

$$I_\text{total}=\frac{V}{R_\text{eff}}$$

This is used to calculate the total current in Parallel or series cicuits

$$V_\text{parallel}=I_\text{total}R_\text{total}$$

The above formula is straightforward.

---

Waves:
$$v=\lambda\nu$$
where $v$ is velocity, $\lambda$ is wavelength and $\nu$ is the frequency.

$$T=\frac{1}{\nu}$$
$T$ being the period

The above just contain a basic description of formulae written by me

---

A great resource available on the internet is Khan Academy, where things are explained simply so that they are understandable to high school students.

https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/electricity-and-magnetism
https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/waves-and-optics

Another excellent source is an introductory course from MIT OCW.

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2002/

Comment: in his example $v=\lambda f$

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others said above, $R_{eff}$ in the two cases are for series and parallel combination respectively.

That v in waves section is the velocity of the wave packet and T is the time period.